# how do I change 2019-01-14T22:45:07+0100 to 2019-01-14 22:45:07 in Postgres? It is Facebook data stored in a text format

Tags: postgresql, datetime

I want to change the date formats in PostgreSQL from the first instance to the second example in the code below.

```
2019-01-14T22:45:07+0100
```

to

```
2019-01-14 22:45:07
```

Comment: Where are you seeing `2019-01-14T22:45:07+0100` as that is not a Postgres default? Is the field this is coming from a `timestamp` or `timestamptz` type or a text type? *Add answers as update to your question*.

Comment: It happens to be facebook data stored in a Postgres DB in a text format

Comment: 1) You should probably change that to `timestamptz` type to make it easier to work with when doing datetime operations. 2) See [Data Type formatting](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-formatting.html). So something like: `select to_timestamp('2019-01-14T22:45:07+0100', 'YYYY-MM-DDTHH24:mi:ss'); 2019-01-14 00:05:07-08`. Note it is transformed into a `timestamptz` value.

Comment: I am using the dbt cloud IDE. It doesn't recognize timestampz, only timestamp. The challenge is getting rid of the 'T'.

Comment: 1) So you can't do the `select to_timestamp(...)`? 2) Why do you need to get rid of the 'T', that is ISO correct format? 3) If you want to just do string manipulation: `select replace('2019-01-14T22:45:07+0100', 'T', ' '); 2019-01-14 22:45:07+0100`

Comment: I would leave the T but the client wants it formatted a certain way. I will try out the replace function you just showed me.

Comment: This is a `timestamptz` type on PostgreSQL. You can cast this type to `timestamp`,  Example:  `select '2019-01-14T22:45:07+0100'::timestamp`